# What does RunInstances:SV00? under lineItem/Operation mean in AWS billing report?

Tags: amazon-web-services, report, billing

My AWS billing report shows for example RunInstances:SV001 under lineItem/Operation. Meaning of RunInstances is obvious but what is the SV00? about?

Thanks

Comment: An internal billing code?

Comment: Thank you. Would that not be a custom tag though?

Comment: I meant an Amazon internal billing code, not yours.

Comment: Any idea what they may represent? I see SV001, SV002 and SV004

Answer (score 5):

`RunInstances:SV001` means you are running EC2 spot instances in VPC zone #1. Relatively, `SV002` could mean running EC2 spot instances in VPC zone #2.

By far there is no documentation stating the meaning of those values, and AWS may change that at any time.

Just for your information, here is a list of what I've summarized so far by analyzing the billing csv:

```
'RunInstances':  'Amazon EC2 running Linux/UNIX'
'RunInstances:000g': 'Amazon EC2 running SUSE Linux'
'RunInstances:0010': 'Amazon EC2 running Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
'RunInstances:0002': 'Amazon EC2 running Windows'
'RunInstances:0006':'Amazon EC2 running Windows with SQL Server Standard'
'RunInstances:0102': 'Amazon EC2 running Windows with SQL Server Enterprise'
'RunInstances:0202': 'Amazon EC2 running Windows with SQL Server Web'
'RunInstances:0800': 'Amazon EC2 running Windows (Bring your own license)'
```

Comment: For platform details see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/billing-info-fields.html  But, mapping SV<num> to Region name is still not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has documented at least some of the RunInstances codes [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ami-billing-info.html) and specifically discusses what the SV code means. I recommend referring to that documentation in case they add more codes. Should that link no longer work in the future, it's current contents are excerpted below (bold mine):

- RunInstances: Linux/UNIX
- RunInstances:00g0: Red Hat BYOL Linux
- RunInstances:0010: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
- RunInstances:0100: SQL Server Enterprise
- RunInstances:0004: SQL Server Standard
- RunInstances:0200: SQL Server Web
- RunInstances:000g: SUSE Linux
- RunInstances:0002: Windows
- RunInstances:0800: Windows BYOL
- RunInstances:0102: Windows with SQL Server Enterprise *
- RunInstances:0006: Windows with SQL Server Standard *
- RunInstances:0202: Windows with SQL Server Web *

* If two software licenses are associated with an AMI, the Platform details field shows both.

If you are running Spot Instances, the lineitem/Operation on your AWS Cost and Usage Report might be different from the Usage operation value that is listed here. **For example, if lineitem/Operation displays RunInstances:0010:SV006, it means that Amazon EC2 is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Spot Instance-hour in US East (Virginia) in VPC Zone #6.**

Comment: Providing a link is welcome, and this sounds like a useful reference. But your answer should stand on its own even if the link is later removed. Can you edit your answer to include the definition for `SV00`/`SV001`?